# Purpose of NameQualifier attribute within the NameID element

Tags: saml, saml-2.0

According to the SAML 2.0 specification, the `NameQualifier` attribute in the `NameID` element is "the security or administrative domain that qualifies the name. This attribute provides a means to federate names from disparate user stores without collision."

My question is: can the "disparate user stores" be within the same IDP? If so, given that the `Format` of the `NameID` will be `urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified`, does the IDP have the right to send anything in the name qualifier as long as it is unique to each of its datastore?

Does this mean that in order for the SP (provided it receives requests from different IDPs) to achieve uniqueness, it has to consider the remote entity ID, `NameQualifier` and `NameID` value?